# WordPress SDL Translation for shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, language-translation, wordpress-shortcode

I have some sort of sort of shortcodes like `[wp-text text="Lorem Impsum etc" button_text="Read More"][/wp-text]`.

I want to extract this shortcode from **`post content field`** and then send these two attributes: `text` and `button_text` for translation to SDL World Server.

After getting response from SDL, I want to replace that shortcode accordingly.

Any Suggestion or Help?

Comment: Please add shortcodes code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion about your approach:

1. Parse the *shortcode* attributes

Having the content you can parse the variable and extract all short code attributes with the provided Wordpress function [shortcode_parse_atts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_parse_atts)

2. For each parsed value make a API call to the provided SDL World Server REST API (*Or for better performance you can group all the translations and translate them with one complex API call if supported from the API*)
3. After getting the response replace the original strings with the translated strings.

Here is example *pseudo code* in PHP:

```
$shotcode_attributes = shortcode_parse_atts( $post->post_content );

foreach ( $shortcode_attributes as $attribute => $value ) {
  // Make SDL World Server API call refer to the API documentation for the exact way
  $translated_value = $sdlApiClient->translate( $value );

  // Replace the translated value.
  // You can be more precise here ensuring that the value is inside the shortcode
  $post->post_content = str_replace(
    "{$attribute}=\"{$value}\"", 
    "{$attribute}=\"{$translated_value}\"", 
    $post->post_content
  );
}
```

You can also research and examine the provided [SDL WordPress Connector](https://www.sdl.com/download/sdl-wordpress-connector-quick-start-guide/103922/)

Comment: Thank you @plamen-nikolov for this sharp answer. you solved 70% issue for me

Comment: I have edited my answer in the part of the replacement, there was no need of the square brackets.